# MVC 4 - String Custom Template messing with Enums

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, enums

I have a custom template `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplate/String.cshtml` and it seems to be causing the Exception:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Proj.Models.EnumType', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.
```

It seems to only happen to `Enums`.  It also goes away if I remove the template. The template doesn't seem to cause it, I don't think it's even making it that far. I can put ANYTHING in there and the exception is the same.

So... can I not use an `@Html.EditorFor` with a `model` with an `enum` if I have a `custom template`?

Some context:

Model:

```
namespace Proj.Models
{

    public enum EnumType
    {
      A = 0,
      B = 1,
      C = 2,
    }

    public class Mod
    {
      [Required]
      public String Name;

      [Required]
      public EnumType Letter;
    }

}
```

View:

```
@model Proj.Models.Mod
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m) // Exception happens here
```

Comment: You really need to provide more context than this.  What does your model look like?  What does your view and template look like?  What does your controller action method look like?  Give us something to recreate the problem with.

Comment: Well, first the Required attribute is pointless because Enum's are a value type, and they cannot be Null, thus they will always have a value, and thus will never fail Required validation.  Secondly, what is it that you expect the EditorFor to do with an Enum?  There is no "Enum Selector" method.  Finally, you are not actually providing a model type.

Comment: @MystereMan: I was thinking the `Mod` class was the model. And I have the required there for client side validation. Without the template, it would just display a textbox where I could enter the name I wanted.

Comment: That's not how it works.  You can't enter the name of an Enum and have it magically work.  An enum is actually an int (which is why it's values are 0, 1, 2, etc..).  Your EditorTemplate is using a string.. If Mod is your model, then you should specify Mod is your model, not leave @model empty.  As for the Required field, you aren't listening to me.  An enum is a value type.  It cannot be null, therefore validation is pointless.  If you leave the field empty it will still contain a default value, it cannot fail validation.

Comment: I'm aware that an Enum is stored as an Int32... However I also know that when I pass a model with an Enum type to an EditorFor it displays it with a textbox.  Also, if I leave that textbox empty and try to submit it, it will tell me the field is required. (I THOUGHT this was because of the Required attribute).

Comment: Now you're really getting confusing, why are you making your model type to be EnumType when your model type is Mod?  No, value types are always required.  Remove the Required attribute and you will see what I mean.

Comment: I tried it and you're right, it still forces you to have it...  Sorry, I need to do a better job with my example... Evidently I'm being VERY careless with it.  The model type is `Mod`

Comment: The end result, however, is that MVC does not parse Enums to their textual representation.  If you want to do that, you will have to write the code yourself.  See examples like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890983/asp-net-mvc-using-a-enum-as-part-of-the-model

Comment: Without the custom template, `EditorFor` displays it with a textbox. No extra code.

Comment: Yes, it displays it, but it does not parse it when you post it back.

Comment: Fair enough... so I guess to answer my question, I have to hide the enum to be able to use the custom template at all for any strings because of the way the `EditorFor` displays the enums.

Comment: The problem is that the Enum is being converted to a string, so you can either apply a different (more specific) template to it, ignore it (with a data attribute), or change your template to use a model type of object instead, then test whether or not the type is actually string or not.

Comment: So could I make a custom template for `EnumType`?

Comment: Yes, you can.  You may need to use the UIHint attribute to tell it which template to use, as i'm not sure if the framework will choose the right template automatically for enums.

Comment: UIHint seems to only be ok on a field, not the entire class. Would I put it on each field?

Comment: Also, when I changed the template from `@model String` to `@model dynamic`, the problem seemed to be fixed.

Comment: Why would you put it on a class?  Your problem is with a specific field.

Comment: Yea I originally tried to put it on the Enum itself... Obviously... this was dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found to work for me.

In your **template**, make sure you declare your model as nullable enum type. Then, in code, check to see if it has a value and based on that do appropriate formatting.

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Proj.Models.EnumType?>

@{
    Proj.Models.EnumType v = Model.HasValue ? Model.Value : {*some-default-value*};

    @Html.{*Your-formatter-here*};            
}
```